# Issues with irrecord lirc function

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, remote-control, lirc

I am trying to setup a remote to work with an IR reciever that I recently purchased using my raspberry pi, I've installed LIRC according to the following tutorial

https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/2021/how-to-send-and-receive-ir-signals-with-a-raspberry-pi

now the problem arises when I try and record to setup a specific remote, it saves all the values as 0x0,

here is the console output when setting up the remote that doesn't work

```
Running as regular user pi
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
irrecord: could not open logfile "/home/pi/.cache/irrecord.log"
irrecord: Permission denied

irrecord -  application for recording IR-codes for usage with lirc
Copyright (C) 1998,1999 Christoph Bartelmus(lirc@bartelmus.de)

This program will record the signals from your remote control
and create a config file for lircd.

A proper config file for lircd is maybe the most vital part of this
package, so you should invest some time to create a working config
file. Although I put a good deal of effort in this program it is often
not possible to automatically recognize all features of a remote
control. Often short-comings of the receiver hardware make it nearly
impossible. If you have problems to create a config file READ THE
DOCUMENTATION at https://sf.net/p/lirc-remotes/wiki

If there already is a remote control of the same brand available at
http://sf.net/p/lirc-remotes you might want to try using such a
remote as a template. The config files already contains all
parameters of the protocol used by remotes of a certain brand and
knowing these parameters makes the job of this program much
easier. There are also template files for the most common protocols
available. Templates can be downloaded using irdb-get(1). You use a
template file by providing the path of the file as a command line
parameter.

Please take the time to finish the file as described in
https://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/wiki/Checklist/ an send it
to  <lirc@bartelmus.de> so it can be made available to others.

Press RETURN to continue.

Checking for ambient light  creating too much disturbances.
Please don't press any buttons, just wait a few seconds...

No significant noise (received 0 bytes)

Enter name of remote (only ascii, no spaces) :notworking
Using notworking.lircd.conf as output filename

Now start pressing buttons on your remote control.

It is very important that you press many different buttons randomly
and hold them down for approximately one second. Each button should
generate at least one dot but never more than ten dots of output.
Don't stop pressing buttons until two lines of dots (2x80) have
been generated.

Press RETURN now to start recording.
................................................................................
Got gap (108172 us)}

Please keep on pressing buttons like described above.
.....................................................................................................................................................Cannot find any gap, using an arbitrary 50 ms one. If you have a
regular remote for e. g., a TV or such this is probably a point
where you hit control-C. However, technical hardware like air
condition gear often works without any gap. If you think it's
reasonable that your remote lacks gap you can proceed.
Press RETURN to continue.


Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)
KEY_UP

Now hold down button "KEY_UP".

Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)
KEY_DOWN

Now hold down button "KEY_DOWN".

Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)
KEY_LEFT

Now hold down button "KEY_LEFT".

Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)
KEY_RIGHT

Now hold down button "KEY_RIGHT".

Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)
KEY_OK

Now hold down button "KEY_OK".

Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)

Checking for toggle bit mask.
Please press an arbitrary button repeatedly as fast as possible.
Make sure you keep pressing the SAME button and that you DON'T HOLD
the button down!.
If you can't see any dots appear, wait a bit between button presses.

Press RETURN to continue.
...Cannot find any toggle mask.

Successfully written config file notworking.lircd.conf
```

Here is what the config file that's generated looks like

[image: Bad Config]

Now, if I setup another remote I have laying around I get a correct config file

[image: Good Config]

Here is a picture of the two remotes sitting side by side, the remote on the left is the one that is not working
[image: Remote on the left is not working, remote on the right is]

I've tried using this tutorial too to no avail
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235256

does anyone know what's going on here?